# HTTP request error from framework 4 application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I try to use my WebService from `.NET` application (`.NET Framework 4`, `C#`, `VS 2010`) and I got this exception:

> An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://... This
>   could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured
>   properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by
>   a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

Does anyone know how to fix the code?

Comment: This worked in previous .Net framework versions?

Comment: No,I tried with .NET Framework 3.0 and it's also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```